# DBT run failing due to error in re_data_schema_changes

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, dbt

I am building my warehouse using dbt. I am using the re_data package. My dbt run is failing on

> 15:06:52  46 of 53 ERROR creating incremental model
> DATA.re_data_schema_changes.... [ERROR in 2.03s]
>
> Database Error in model re_data_schema_changes
> (models/alerts/re_data_schema_changes.sql) 15:07:00    040050 (22000):
> SQL compilation error: cannot change column ID from type
> VARCHAR(16777216) to VARCHAR(32) because reducing the byte-length of a
> varchar is not supported.

Looking at the `re_data_schema_changes.sql` code generated during dbt run, this is what the SQL is:

```
  select 
        md5(cast(coalesce(cast(table_name as 
    varchar
), '') || '-' || coalesce(cast(column_name as 
    varchar
), '') || '-' || coalesce(cast(detected_time as 
    varchar
), '') as 
    varchar
)) as id
```

Has someone run into this issue?

Not sure if there is a way to bypass this error with re_data package.

Comment: why are you casting the text/varchar to a limited size, Snowflake has zero performance gains from limiting text column width, and the the default 16mb aka `varchar`/`text` is perfectly fine as it is..